# Cmake Cannot Find Autoware_msgsConfig

Tags: c++, cmake, path, config, prefix

I am attempting to create a ROS node that will take in Autoware's `DetectedObjectArray.msg`. However, when I attempt to build the node I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "autoware_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    autoware_msgsConfig.cmake
    autoware_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "autoware_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "autoware_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "autoware_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

I have attempted to set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the location of the config in the autoware enviroment using the following code in the terminal:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/cimar/autoware.ai/install/autoware_msgs/share/autoware_msgs/cmake
```

but I receive the same error. I have also attempted to set this path using

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/autoware.ai/install/autoware_msgs/share/autoware_msgs/cmake")
```

Attached below is my `CMakeLists.txt` for this node.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(OTM_Manager)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/autoware.ai/install/autoware_msgs/share/autoware_msgs/cmake") 

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  autoware_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(OTM_Manager src/OTM_Manager.cpp)

target_link_libraries(OTM_Manager
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(OTM_Manager
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

install(TARGETS OTM_Manager
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)


install(DIRECTORY launch/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

Comment: "I have attempted to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the location of the config" - Look error message carefully: Variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should contain **installation prefix**, not the directory which contain the configuration file. In your case the installation prefix is most likely `/home/autoware.ai/install/autoware_msgs` (without `share` and `cmake` subdirectories).

Comment: Applying the suggested path did not work. Is there a way to identify the correct path?

Comment: You may try to run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` option. With that option `find_package` should show exact paths which are tried. This output may give you a hint why current setting of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` does not work and what setting is needed.